# Feedparser returns only first entry of ATOM feed

Tags: python, feedparser

I updated my (already) working code from python2.7 to python3.5 and the following problem suddenly appears.

By parsing the given ATOM feed with many entries (correct syntax), feedparser 5.2.1. returns **only the first entry** of the feed and of course the "meta" data of the feed.

My (unmodified) code:

```
feed_data = feedparser.parse("www.myfeed.com/myfeeds.atom")
for entry in feed_data.entries:
    print(entry)
```

**output**

```
{'uid':'99999','author':'XY', ...more content of the first entry...}
{}
```

The next (second) entry is empty... and the other entries are not even listed... The lenght of feed_data.entries is **2** (it should be 78).

**UPDATE**

Now (today) I get 3 entries as output, because one new entry was appended at the beginning of the entry-list, so I guess it is an "encoding" problem with the specific 3rd entry in the current feed.

Any ideas how to fix the problem?

Comment: Guessing there is something wrong w/your atom feed.  That code would work fine on a diff feed such as: https://www.theregister.co.uk/data_centre/networks/headlines.atom

Comment: It works fine under python 2.7 (and maybe an older version von feedparser) with exactly the same (working) atom feed, but under python3.5 it fails.

Comment: It might be tough to troubleshoot without being able to pull the exact feed you are trying to pull.

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys,

Python3.5 is not supported yet. But the support for this python version is prepared in the develop branch of the github project ([see here](https://github.com/kurtmckee/feedparser/blob/develop/NEWS)).

It works with this development version of feedparser, so I'll try this and might wait (nothing happend sind one year) until the official release of this "feature".